# Should I use a buffer or a simple output with a signal?

Tags: vhdl

When I implement a clock divider, I often wonder whether I shold use a buffer or a regular output with a signal. Consider the following codes :

Option 1 - **Output with signal**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity divider is
port (Clock : in bit;
      OutputFreq : out bit);
end divider;

architecture behave of divider is
signal Counter : integer range 0 to 155;
signal CurrentState : bit;
begin
process(Clock)
begin

if Clock'event and Clock = '1' then
    if Counter < 155 then
        Counter <= Counter + 1;
    else
        Counter <= 0;
        CurrentState <= not CurrentState;
    end if;
end if;

OutputFreq <= CurrentState;
end process;
end behave;
```

Option 2 - **Buffer**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity divider is
port (Clock : in bit;
      OutputFreq : buffer bit);
end divider;

architecture behave of divider is
signal Counter : integer range 0 to 155;
begin
process(Clock)
begin

if Clock'event and Clock = '1' then
    if Counter < 155 then
        Counter <= Counter + 1;
    else
        Counter <= 0;
        OutputFreq <= not OutputFreq;
    end if;
end if;

end process;
end behave;
```

Both of these codes produce the exact same output. So, which one I should use and why?

Comment: Why don't you use `inout`?

Comment: Because my teacher never does :)

Comment: Yeah. That is a valid reason. :)

Comment: buffer is a port mode, OutputFreq is signal in both cases. "A port interface list consists entirely of interface signal declarations.", IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with solution 1 and add an explicit flip-flop for the output.

The sole reason is, that using buffer ports is not recommended by some synthesis tools and in literature. If there is a real reason behind this, or if this has become cargo-cult programming - I don't know.

One upside of using a buffer instead of a dedicated signal is, that you save the signal. That is one less identifier to care about. In complex designs with lots of signals that makes your code easier to read and understand.

By the way, you can optimize your code a little bit:

```
if Clock'event and Clock = '1' then
    if Counter = 155 then
        Counter <= 0;
        CurrentState <= not CurrentState;
    else
        Counter <= Counter + 1;
    end if;
end if;
```

Using a equal compare operator instead of a less/greater operator will likely use less FPGA resources because comparing for equal can be done with a hand full of inverters and a huge AND gate. This gets absorbed into a few FPGA lookup tables. Comparing two numbers for less or greater needs more resources like carry chains as it is basically a subtracter that is needed.

Comment: Well...why arent they recommended by some synthesis tools and in literature? I don't understand...

Comment: Some synthesis tools don't allow connecting a buffer to a different out port, so you'll run into problems in hierarchical designs.

Comment: I have been told not to use buffer so often with such vehemence that I never dared question it. I wonder if someone knows the deep reason? I just feel it represented something in 87 that doesn't translate to newer technologies. VHDL-2008 allows to reference an output port from the architecture.